# Find smallest positive number that is Divisible from given range using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, range, division

for example : 2520 is the smallest positive that is divided by each number from 1 to 10.

Please help me logic to find smallest positive number from 1 to 20 using SQL

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you have already tried!

Comment: Tried using c logic. but its wrong way have been informed .

Answer (score 1):

It is 13 693 680 ? http://rextester.com/APWPAS87659

Assuming the result is < 15 000 000

Brute force :

```
with
number as (
SELECT TOP (15000000) 
    CONVERT(BIGINT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.object_id)) as n
FROM
    sys.all_objects AS s1 
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s3
)
select
   min(n),
   max(n),
   min(
   case
   when n%20 + n%19 + n%18 + n%16 + n%15 + n%14 + n%13 + n%12 + n%11 + n%10 + n%9 + n%8 + n%7 + n%6 + n%5 + n%4 + n%3 + n%2 + n%1 = 0 then n
   end)
from
   number
;
```

==> very long

Assuming the solution is a multiple of 10 :

```
with
number as (
SELECT TOP (1500000) 
    CONVERT(BIGINT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.object_id)) * 10 as n
FROM
    sys.all_objects AS s1 
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s3
)
select
   min(n),
   max(n),
   min(
   case
   when n%20 + n%19 + n%18 + n%16 + n%15 + n%14 + n%13 + n%12 + n%11 + n%10 + n%9 + n%8 + n%7 + n%6 + n%5 + n%4 + n%3 + n%2 + n%1 = 0 then n
   end)
from
   number
;
```

Just x10 faster.

Assuming the result is a multiple of 2520 (smallest positive that is divided by each number from 1 to 10) and 6 000*2 520 > 15 000 000)

```
with
number as (
SELECT TOP (6000) 
    CONVERT(BIGINT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.object_id)) * 2520 as n
FROM
    sys.all_objects AS s1 
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
)
select
   min(n),
   max(n),
   min(
   case
   when n%20 + n%19 + n%18 + n%16 + n%15 + n%14 + n%13 + n%12 + n%11 = 0 then n
   end)
from
   number
```

very fast (about x2520 more faster the first proposal).